# Showing something is a vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: real-analysis

I'm asked to show that something forms a vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. I'm not sure what the term "pointwise addition and scalar multiplication" means in this context. HOw does it change from the usual vector space definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a way of specifiying what you mean by addition and scalar multiplication. For instance, suppose you have two functions $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. What does it mean to add them? That is, what is $f+g$ ?

One (very common) way of defining the addition of two functions is by saying the addition is 'pointwise'. This means that $f+g$ is a function, and the value of that function at a point $x$ is given by adding the values of $f$ at $x$ and $g$ at $x$. That is,
$$(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$

Pointwise scalar multiplication is very similar. We can multiply a function $f$ by some scalar $\lambda$ to get a new function $\lambda f$, which is given by:
$$(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda f(x)$$

There are multiple ways of making a set of functions into a vector space by defining different types of addition and scalar multiplication, but this is well and truly the simplest.